# Any way to speed up this file parsing algorithm?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, algorithm, .net-4.0

I wrote a small algorithm using LINQ to read in a bunch of files (about 30mb) and store them in memory, currently it takes about a minute for the program to finish reading in all files, however I need this process to only take a few seconds.

Code:

```
List<ClimateDailyData> dailyData = new List<ClimateDailyData>();
if (File.Exists(FileName))
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileName);
    try
    {
        List<string[]> lines = 
            Regex.Split(reader.ReadToEnd(), Environment.NewLine)
                .Where(l => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(l))
                .Select(l => l.Trim().Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' })
                .Where(f => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(f))
                .Select(f => f.Trim())
                .ToArray())
                .ToList();
        Latitude = double.Parse(lines[0][0]);
        Longitude = double.Parse(lines[0][1]);
        lines.RemoveRange(0, 2);
        foreach (string[] fields in lines)
        {
            ClimateDailyData dayData = new ClimateDailyData();
            dayData.DayDate = DateTime.ParseExact(fields[0], "yyyyMMdd", 
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
            dayData.MaxTemp = double.Parse(fields[2]);
            dayData.MinTemp = double.Parse(fields[3]);
            dayData.Rain = double.Parse(fields[4]);
            dayData.Pan = double.Parse(fields[5]);
            dailyData.Add(dayData);
        }
    }
    finally { reader.Close(); }
}
SetValue(() => DailyData, dailyData);
```

Can anyone sugest how I could speed this code up? The majority of the time seems to be involved with parsing the individual file fields (especially the date field).

However if it cannot be sped up I will simply make it so each individual file is loaded as required.

Thanks,
Alex.

**EDIT:**
Also I decided to just store a few fields from each file rather then all file data and then load the rest of the data in a seperate thread and make it avaiable to the user as it finishes loading.

So now it only takes 2.7seconds.

Comment: Have you actually run your code through a profiler like dotTrace and confirmed your suspicions about what is taking up most of the time?

Comment: *a bunch of files (about 30mb)* - size of all files, or size of each file? And add the count of files please.

Comment: Why the RegEx?  It would seem to overcomplicate things from a readability/mantainabilty point of view.

Comment: For starters, remove the `Regex` and call `File.ReadAllLines`

Comment: Ok there are 30 files (could be up to 200) which together total 36.1mb, largest being somewhere around 4mb.

Comment: Did not know about the File.ReadAllLines(), but it took the execution time from 4.27sec to 3.7sec, so was much more efficient. In terms of locating where all the time is being spent it was shown through the VS2010 performance analysis tool that the for each loop is using 84% of the time in that code snippet.

Comment: I know this is probably a dumb question, but why is a two-dimensional array being generated from the above code?  Is it because there are two delimiters (I kind of doubt it, but I can't figure this out even after looking on MSDN and Google, so I figured I'd ask).

Comment: @Tim: After the Select, we've got an `IEnumerable<string[]>` (which means that the second `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` doesn't make sense to me) so when we convert that to a list, it's a `List<string[]>`.

Comment: @Alex: Gabe's now pointed out how confusing your indentation is, around the "nested" query. It's *really* worth making your code as readable as possible.

Comment: Another comment; you are parsing doubles here. One mistake (IMHO) in .NET is that double.Parse picks up the current culture. In some cultures the decimal delimiter is ',' not '.' (ie Norwegian, Swedish and others). IMO that's why one should always use the double.Parse overloads that takes a CultureInfo (I tend to use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) when parsing files that are not dependent on culture. Interestingly the WPF team has chosen english culture as standard culture for WPF UI when IMO in the case of UI it would make sense to pickup the current UI culture. Oh well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in comments, it's an odd way of reading lines - but I wouldn't use `File.ReadAllLines`, I'd use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) if you're using .NET 4 - that only reads one line at a time.

Beyond that - you definitely don't need to call `ToArray` *and* `ToList`... I'd also use `Select` and `ToList` with `Skip` to create `dailyData`. Also, `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` already returns `false` if the string is empty, so you can remove those calls.

After splitting, you're currently trimming and removing any empty/whitespace entries. You can remove empty entries with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` and *if* you're confident that the only whitespace in a line would be space or tab, you then don't need to worry about trimming or anything else. If you have *other* whitespace which needs trimming, it could still be a problem - but I doubt that's the case. One big benefit of that is that you can use the array returned by `Split` directly, rather than copying it to another collection.

```
private static readonly char[] Delimiters = { ' ', '\t' };

...

List<ClimateDailyData> dailyData;
if (!File.Exists(FileName))
{
    dailyData = new List<ClimateDailyData>();
}
else
{
    dailyData = File.ReadLines(FileName)
       .Where(l => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l))
       .Select(l => l.Trim()
                     .Split(Delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
       .Select(fields => new ClimateDailyData
               {
                   DayDate = DateTime.ParseExact(fields[0], "yyyyMMdd",
                                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                                 DateTimeStyles.None),
                   MaxTemp = double.Parse(fields[2]),
                   MinTemp = double.Parse(fields[3]),
                   Rain = double.Parse(fields[4]),
                   Pan = double.Parse(fields[5])
               })
       .ToList();
}
SetValue(() => DailyData, dailyData);
```

Comment: Jon, reading line by line (assuming 10 lines) kinda takes more time than reading at 1 shot right. i mean it first read first line and gives you 2 process that line, by then your processor is upto some ting else job and again it has to context switch to this job and again disk access. I mean its not at 1 stretch disck access. So dont you think so?? Correct me please. thanks

Comment: The `Latitude` and `Longitude` are never used, so you don't need to call `ToList`, meaning you can define it as `var lines` and skip the listification step.

Comment: Thanks, that brought it down to about 2.7seconds

Comment: @zenwalker: No, I'd expect it to take *less* time - because the OS may well be able to keep reading the file in the background (into its cache) while you're processing it. It also means it doesn't need to create an array of exactly the right size. But the best thing to do is try it.

Comment: @Alex: I've just noticed something about the code which confused me - you're calling Split but then acting as if you're still working with strings... that won't work. I suspect the code you've posted isn't the real code, is it?

Comment: @Jon: It looks like you're getting confused by the indentation. See my answer for (hopefully) proper indentation.

Comment: @Gabe: Yes, you're absolutely right. That's *horrible* indentation. Will edit mine too...

Comment: @Jon: Check my answer again. Is there any reason the nested query can't just be replaced with `l.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' },                                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))`?

Comment: @Gabe: Probably not... and creating the char array once would also be slightly faster...

Comment: @Gabe: Actually, yes - because that won't remove *pure whitespace* entries... and it won't trim entries either. Admittedly it would only make a difference in cases where there was non-tab/space whitespace, which is unlikely... will add that into my answer.

Comment: if you remove the .ToList after the l.Trim().Split(..) you'll reduce the time by roughly 1/3 of the parsing. Or to be more precise with random valid data for 1000000 lines in memory that's what happened when I tested

Comment: @Rune: Ooh, yes, I'd forgotten that - it was required before due to the Where/Select bits. Editing...

Comment: Just FYI: Because it's fun I profiled the current code sample by JS (% in exclusive samples): Enumerable.ToList 42%, double.Parse 26%, DateTime.ParseExact 18% (I reverse-engineered a 30Meg dataset from the code)

Answer (score 2):

It depends a lot on the size of your data, but if you're willing to put some effort in you can see much better performance than that in .NET.

...

<strike>This will certainly be faster.</strike> It's not. After reflecting in and checking it out, it seems it uses a special string construct internally to parse out the date. That'll teach me for opening my mouth without profiling first :).

Getting rid of intermediate representations and working directly from char[]s will help for sure though. For the fastest implementation you want to do it all by pulling from FileStream into a fixed char[] buffer by using StreamReader, only creating string instances for conversion. I can also say for sure that Regex and String.Format will absolutely murder your performance.

I recently wrote a xml parser using this technique combined with a yielding IEnumerable.  Even on my SSD disk access is over 95% of execution time.

However, I'm dealing with files in the 200MB-2GB range.  This stuff is hard to get right if you're not used to it and in your case going that far may be overkill.

Comment: Have you actually measured that? When I try it runs 25% slower.

Comment: Not the DateTime example directly.  I'm working with messy bank data that can have invalid date values and so I use my own class.  That is very surprising though, as I've found String.Format to be unreasonably slow in my own code.  Now I need to reflect in and see what DateTime is doing.

Comment: Thanks for calling me out.  I assumed that because other string format based functions were slow, so was DateTime.  Words have been eaten :).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all the time is being spent creating lists and parsing dates, eliminating those could definitely help. Here's a combination of [Jon's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117151/c-net-anyway-to-speed-up-this-file-parsing-algorithm/7117339#7117339) and [Rick's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117151/c-net-anyway-to-speed-up-this-file-parsing-algorithm/7117346#7117346) answers:

```
List<ClimateDailyData> dailyData;
if (!File.Exists(FileName))
{
    dailyData = new List<ClimateDailyData>();
}
else
{
    dailyData = File
             .ReadLines(FileName)
             .Where(line => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
             .Skip(2)
             .Select(line => line.Split(new [] { ' ', '\t' },
                                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
             .Select(fields => new ClimateDailyData
              {
                   DayDate = new DateTime(
                       int.Parse(fields[0].Substring(0, 4)),
                       int.Parse(fields[0].Substring(4, 2)),
                       int.Parse(fields[0].Substring(6, 2))),
                   MaxTemp = double.Parse(fields[2]),
                   MinTemp = double.Parse(fields[3]),
                   Rain = double.Parse(fields[4]),
                   Pan = double.Parse(fields[5])
              })
             .ToList();
}
SetValue(() => DailyData, dailyData);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. I does not use those fancy Linq queries :-), but it has some advantages:

- you don't read more than the needed fields
- you never allocate any List or Array which saves the memory especially for big collections, and should pleases the garbage collector (you can always do a `new List<ClimateDailyData>(...)` at then end if needed)
- I also didn't use Split in case the lines are really long. It's all 'yield' based (the framework should have an IEnumerable version of split IMHO...)

  ```
  public static IEnumerable<ClimateDailyData> ReadDailyData(string fileName)
  {
      if (fileName == null)
          throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");

      if (!File.Exists(fileName))
          yield break;

      int lineIndex = -1;
      foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(fileName))
      {
          lineIndex++;
          ClimateDailyData dayData = new ClimateDailyData();
          int i = 0;
          foreach (string field in ReadDailyDataFields(line))
          {
              if (lineIndex == 0)
              {
                  // handle latitude stuff
                  continue;
              }
              switch(i)
              {
                  case 0:
                      dayData.DayDate = DateTime.ParseExact(field, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
                      break;
                  case 2:
                      dayData.MaxTemp = double.Parse(field);
                      break;
                  case 3:
                      dayData.MinTemp = double.Parse(field);
                      break;
                  case 4:
                      dayData.Rain = double.Parse(field);
                      break;
                  case 5:
                      dayData.Pan = double.Parse(field);
                      break;
                  default:
                      break;
              }
              i++;
          }
          yield return dayData;
      }
  }

  public static IEnumerable<string> ReadDailyDataFields(string text)
  {
      if (text == null)
          yield break;

      int lastPos = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
      {
          if ((text[i] == ' ') || (text[i] == '\t'))
          {
              if (i > lastPos)
              {
                  string field = text.Substring(lastPos, i - lastPos).Trim();
                  if (field.Length > 0)
                      yield return field;
                  lastPos = i + 1;
              }
          }
      }

      if (text.Length > lastPos)
      {
          string field = text.Substring(lastPos, text.Length - lastPos).Trim();
          if (field.Length > 0)
              yield return field;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: While I like yield return in general when you are going for top performance a signature like this can help reduce allocations further: void ReadDailyDataFields(string text, List<string> output). Also when working on parsers I found that defining a SubString class to avoid splitting a string is many individual strings gave significant performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

- Meassure where most time is spend. Don't guess!
- Use `File.ReadAllLines` so you get rid of the unneeded `RegEx.Split`
- The call of `Trim` and the check for emptyness can probably be turned around and you can get rid of one check.
- If you change your iteration a little bit, you don't have to build a `List` out of the LINQ result. You can just use an iterator, which will probably reduce memory management overhead.
- Splitting of a single line into an array would happen in the inner loop, which once again will reduce memory allocation overhead.
- `ClimateDailyData` should get a usefull constructor, which should manage the parsing job. It's probably not performance relevant, but will make the code cleaner which is in generall a good thing.